# How to create double nesting serializer in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

While trying to create nested object, i'm getting this error. I may be using incorrect relationship here; need your expert guidance.

`Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('color', 'black), ('transmission', 'auto'), ('mileage', '20kmpl')])": "Vehicle.detail" must be a "Detail" instance`

Django==4.1.7
Python 3.9.13

Expecting

```
{
  "auto_id": "some-uuid",
  "vehicle": [
    {
      "manufacturer": "toyota",
      "year": 2020,
      "detail": {
         "color": "black",
         "transmission": "auto",
         "mileage": "20kmpl"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

model

```
class Auto(models.Model):
    auto_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)


class Detail(model.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    mileage = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    year = models.PostiveIntegerField()
    auto = models.ForeignKey(Auto, related_name='vehicle', on_delete=models.cascade)
    detail = models.ForeignKey(Detail, on_delete=models.cascade)
```

serializer

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ('color', 'transmission', 'mileage')

class VehicleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    detail = DetailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ('manufacturer', 'year', 'detail')
    
class AutoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vehicle = VehicleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Auto
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        vehicle_list = validated_data.pop('vehicle')
        auto = Auto.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for vehicle in vehicle_list:
            Vehicle.objects.create(auto=auto, **vehicle)
        return auto
```

Could you please guide me, where i can convert the ordered dict for detail instance.

Answer (score 0):

In `AutoSerializer`, you also have to process the detail data as a `Detail` object separately, much like how you did it for `Auto` and `Vehicle`:

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        vehicle_list = validated_data.pop('vehicle')
        auto = Auto.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for vehicle in vehicle_list:
            # Pop the detail data
            detail_data = vehicle.pop("detail")
            # Build detail object
            detail = Detail.objects.create(**detail_data) 
            # Assign the FKs
            Vehicle.objects.create(auto=auto, detail=detail, **vehicle)

        return auto
```

Comment: This work when we create a new record, but on deleting `auto_id` cascade deletion is not working i can see `Detail` objects records in the database.

Comment: Ah thats a different problem than what this post is trying to solve. I suggest creating a new question for that.